# Set Custom Form Dropdown value

Tags: list, custom-form

I have a new SharePoint form that I have created for a specific function.  I would like the drop down (type of outage) value by default to be "Leave".  Currently, I have 5 different choices within this dropdown.  How would I go about adding this ability to the list form?

There will be multiple forms associated with this list as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into the list settings and click on the column name of your drop down list. Set the default value to Leave. There isn't anything you need to do on the custom form to achieve this.

Comment: Even if I have different forms set for different things?  This would be a leave form and I may make a sick form.  If I set the default to leave wouldn't that effect all the other forms as well?

Comment: if there are multiple content types sharing this field in the list, then they would all inherit the default value set in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Eric put what I was going to suggest. In response to your comment on his answer, if I understand you are worried about the default value on different forms? IE the leave form, and then the sick form? Each would be set up differently. So you Leave form would have it's drop down choices defaulting to leave and the same for sick except it would default to sick.

Comment: Right, so I have 5 different choices in the drop down but for just the leave form I would like it to default to "leave".

Comment: Are these separate forms? If so, then just set the default value on the leave form to leave. Leave the other forms blank or set them to their own default value.

Comment: These are separate forms, I still have the default new, display, and edit forms as well.  If I want to set the default value for just the leave form, how would I go about it?

Comment: The you would go into list settings for that form, and then the specific column you are choosing from. Down near the bottom, you will see Default value with 2 options. Choice or Calculated. Choose Choice and then type in Leave

Comment: I am not seeing where I can specifically target that form?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your process. I am under the assumption that you are on the leave form. There is a drop down column with multiple choices in it. That drop down default to leave when you set it up.

Comment: That is correct but I do not want other forms to be changed though.  I only want the drop down choice to be defaulted to leave on the leave form only.

Comment: It doesn't like our long conversation. When you change it on one form, it doesn't affect the other forms. So just go to the list setting of the leave form specifically and set the default to the leave form column to Leave.,

Comment: Where in SharePoint can I edit this particular form though?

Comment: Go to the form, then up top you should see list. Over the the left is list settings. Click on that. Halfway down the page is your columns. Choose the column that has the values and you set the default value in there.

Comment: Doing so changes the default value for all associated forms.  I only need the "leave form" to be changed.

Comment: Again, I think I am misunderstanding you. If these are separate individual forms they shouldn't.  Sorry I was unable to help anymore.